# Replace or extract from pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas df that looks something like this:

```
|       df      |    y    |
| ------------- | ------- |
| [30, 2018M01] | [50956] |
| [30, 2018M02] | [48561] |
| [30, 2018M03] | [36487] |
```

I want to transform it to:

```
|     df     |   y   |
| ---------- | ----- |
| 2018-01-01 | 50956 |
| 2018-02-01 | 48561 |
| 2018-03-01 | 36487 |
```

In other words transforming the strings with extract and replace. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: What are the types of the `df` and `y` columns?

Answer (score 0):

It there are `list`s use:

```
df['df'] = pd.to_datetime(df['df'].str[1], format='%YM%m')
df['y'] = df['y'].str[0]
```

It there are `string`s use:

```
df['df'] = pd.to_datetime(df['df'].str.strip('[]').str.split(', ').str[1], format='%YM%m')
df['y'] = df['y'].str.strip('[]')
```